# How to get the state of a modal object.bake

Tags: python

I want to use

`bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT', type='DIFFUSE', use_clear=True)`

to bake material information into textures. When i call object.bake in that way then the bake tool operates in the background and does not block Blenders user interface. This is actually what i like to have. However my problem is that i do not know when the bake is finished.

I just can not see any obvious way how to get this information out of Blender. All i read about how others try to fix this issue sounds extremely complicated to me and that can't be right i suspect.

So what is the trick ? Where can i look at to see if the bake tool is still active, on which material it is currently working and which himage it is currently baking ?

And if it is doable but really complicated to do, is there at least some working simple example which i can use as a starting point?